# Can we search for the user app version and device os by UID in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am implementing firebase analytics in my android and iOS apps. Firebase analytics shows the device types, os version etc ... of all the users on its dashboard. I need to get the installed app version and the device os for a specific user. Can firebase can search for the info by filtering on the user uid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Google Analytics for Firebase does not associate events with a specific Firebase user. Instead events are associated with a device token, which is unique to the device/app, but not associated with a specific user.

If you want to associate events with a specific user of your app, you can [set a User ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid). If you do this, the user ID will show up in BigQuery exports of the analytics data. Last I checked, it won't show up in the Firebase analytics dashboard.

I recommend studying the documentation linked carefully, to ensure you use a user ID that is both allowed, and useful for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your reply, I will try setting the user ID. Have a great day !